# Determinant of bounded matrices with transposes

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

For $A$ an $n \times k$ matrix, $B$ an $n \times n$ matrix, and $I_n$ the identity matrix in $\mathbb R^n$ (where $n$ is some finite positive integer), I need to show for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $p>0$ such that $0<r<p$ and $|B-I_n|<r$ imply $\det(A^TA)\le(1+\epsilon)^2\det(A^TB^TBA)$. I've been trying to find an identity which will make this relatively simple but I can't seem to make any progress.

Edit: Assume $\det(A^TA)>0$

Comment: How do you define $|B - I_n|$?  That is, what do you mean by the absolute value of a matrix?

Comment: The absolute value of a matrix (at least the way I'm using it) is the squareroot of the sum of the squares of all entries in said matrix. All this problem really says is that $B$ is as close to $I_n$ as we want to make it.

Comment: All right.  For future reference, that is usually referred to as the "Frobenius norm" of a matrix.  Close to $I_n$ works too.

Answer (score 0):

It suffices to note that the function 
$$
X \mapsto \det(X^TX)
$$
is continuous and non-zero in a neighborhood of $I$.  It follows that
$$
\lim_{B \to I} \frac{\det(A^TA)}{\det([BA]^T[BA])} =
\frac{\det(A^TA)}{\det([IA]^T[IA])} = 1
$$
The desired conclusion follows.

Comment: Don't you need to show that the function you provided is continuous and non-zero in a neighborhood of $A$, not $I$? If we assume $\det(A^TA)>0$, is this doable?

Comment: Right... I'll think about that

Comment: If we assume $\det(A^TA) > 0$, then this is definitely doable.  It really just comes down to the composition of continuous functions.

Comment: If $\det(A^TA) = 0$, then the inequality holds trivially.